# Get queue message count

Tags: .net, azureservicebus

Im writing a integration test to my service bus , where i will publish a message then verify the message count , the only example i found to this seems outdated , any help would be appreciated

im connecting to the queue with the IQueueClient

```
 queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);

           await queueClient.SendAsync(new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("teste mensagem")));
```

im not finding any method to retrieve the message count, how can i achieve this? or is there another better way to do a integration test on the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve message counts you need to use [`ManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient?view=azure-dotnet).
For queues, it has a [`GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient.getqueueruntimeinfoasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Management_ManagementClient_GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method that returns [`QueueRuntimeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.queueruntimeinfo?view=azure-dotnet) object. This object has a property called `MessageCount`.

You might also want to look at another property it exposes, [`MessageCountDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.messagecountdetails?view=azure-dotnet).